# how to use webpack and bootstrap-sass-loader load bootstrap in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-sass

i really just started learning `webpack`. and i use `rails`. 
i want to use `webpack` to managed my `javascript` library. so i found @justing808 ’s `justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial`.

follow his guide, install `bootstrap-sass-loader`, and add `entry` point and add `loader`.

it look like `bootstrap` javascript was loaded. but i don’t know how to import `scss`.in origin rails project, i place scss file in `app/assets/stylesheets` folder. but `webpack` will package all the files in `app/assets/javascripts/client`

somebody could tell me how to import bootstrap in origin rails project’s scss file?

i can load it like this: `../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/bootstrap/`, looks so bad. and not right, yes?

if i do this the `glyphs` cannot be loaded. and i got some warning

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:5000/a/448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:5000/a/fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:5000/a/e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need file-loader as well as url-loader in order to correctly load fonts etc.